# Expanding a table, with string split by comma using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks something like this - where the second and third columns have strings. I would like to split the string (delimited by commmas)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exploding CSV will probably require a user-defined function, and I don't expect it to not be ugly.  Is there any chance you can normalize your data before it even hits MySQL?

Comment: That second table is still missing the rest of the data right?

Comment: @JorgeCampos. Yeah, the second table is missing data. it would continue my exploding apple and orange for BBC and EFG.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - What do you mean my normalize? Like export it to another tool?

Comment: @SankarMuthuswamy No, I was thinking more along of the lines of normalizing it before it even comes in MySQL.  Get rid of that CSV data if at all possible.

Comment: The problem comes as each row has different number of "fruits" under Col A. and a similar issue with Col B. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I see the problem, no need to explain it to me.  But do you see the problem here?  You have, in a single record, a collection of fruits which are in some related to a collection of labels.  But it is impossible to say _what_ this relationship is, not without external information.

Comment: There's no built-in way to split a string in MySQL. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+split+string for some of the workarounds.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Yeah, I see the issue. Right now this explosion of the table is being handled manually. I'm seeing if its possible to automate it.

Comment: You can use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17942680/460557 It is not pretty but it will do the job.